# How to generate a unique controller for modal views

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to create a new controller object every time when view is rendering? This approach would be more convenient for me, because i deal with modal windows.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have an example of two views being present at the same time using the same controller?

Comment: @kingpin2k just any views in the same template.

Comment: hah, yes, I can see how my question was worded weirdly, I was more wondering how they were using it

Comment: @kingpin2k, Ember always generate views but a controller remains the same for the same views, so I want know how can I make Ember regenerate controllers as well.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of what you're referring to, and how you understand it?  If you want to create a working example you can use the stubbed out starting point at emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: @kingpin2k, Could you have a look [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OJoperIl/1/edit?js,console,output)? In the example you can see, that controller is created once unlike the view object. That's what I mean.

Comment: @j.Armstrong you can use Ember.Evented and notify Controller when View has been inserted and removed from DOM. This way you will achieve exactly what you want. Controller still be created once, but you will get another method (like ini nit()) fire up when View has been crated/destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a way to render a modal dialog with its own controller/view/template, without having to transition to a new route.

This [guide in the Ember Cookbook on "Using Modal Dialogs"](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) provides a nice summary of how to render a modal dialog using a new controller/view/template, and then remove it when you're done.

Update: To use a different controller for each modal, change the second argument passed to the "openModal" action. In the cookbook, they use 'myModal' - that will resolve to:

- App.MyModalController
- App.MyModalView
- 'my_modal' template

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in that guide controller remains the same for all modals. See [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OJoperIl/1/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify how the controller is determined. It is definitely possible to use a different controller for each modal.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `render` helper, for example:

**animal.hbs:**

```
{{render "cat"}}

{{render "hamster"}}
```

In case above `cat` has `CatController` controller, hamster has `HamsterController` controller.

When you use `view` helper:

**animal.hbs:**

```
{{view App.CatView}}

{{view App.HamsterView}}
```

`cat` has `AnimalController` controller and `hamster` has `AnimalController` controller as well.

See [COMPARISON TABLE](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_comparison-table)

BTW. You may want to have a look at [Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html)

Comment: see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [render helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper) may help you. If you supply it with a "model" then a new controller gets created every time you put it in your template.

```
{{#if errorObject}}
  {{render "modal" errorObject}}
{{else}}
  {{render "modal" successObject}}
{{/if}}
```

Will have a different controller for the error state to the success state.

Does that make sense in your context?

Comment: You don't need to supply it with the model in order to create controller. Model is optional parameter.

Comment: @Andre Malan, it will work in the general case, but in my case I use controller to open modal windows. I use the approach described here link and render helper doesn't make sense in my context. –  j. Armstrong 1 hour ago

Comment: @WojciechBednarski it does if you use the same name as the first parameter. If you add a model you get a different instance of the same controller, not a different controller entirely.

j.Armstrong if that is the case the answer by Nick Ragaz makes the most sense.